# Assistance required with a suspected Nihilist Cipher text associated with a 1948 Cold Case

Tags: encryption

I have found a cipher text that shows up as a Nihilist Cipher when entered into the dCode cipher identifier. The text was found in a torn slip of paper bearing the words TAMAM SHUD, the last two words in the Rubaiyat of Omar Khayyam. I have been able to photograph the cipher text but I am not in any way a skilled person in this area. Here's the actual cipher text:
637952 8452G 75332 49465 45469 R3293 295X5 87250 02XN4 33976 38548 49525 84M85 48967 66478 35459

I am hoping that someone could assist or perhaps point me in the right direction to get some assistance.